# Domain does not point to google site

Tags: dns, google-sites

I have a domain that was pointed to a hosting, and it shows in the dns records that has a cname and A record for the ip of the host, the problem is that now i want to use that domain in a google site, i have done the steps to verificate the property of the domain. this is the dns info

```
Domaine                    TTL  Type    Cible
ladietamigliore.it.         0   A   178.32.140.171
www.ladietamigliore.it.     0   A   178.32.140.171
```

i did get that an `A record`has the same subdomain when adding the cname for the google site so i renamed the `A record` and i did added cname for google

```
www.ladietamigliore.it.     0   CNAME   ghs.googlehosted.com.
```

in my dns panel everyting look ok, and have waited the 24h the dns to propagate, but the google site can't see the domain. I have followed the steps as they are so i don't know what am i missing, i have not work with the dns befor so try to be the most clear as possible thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Never set your DNS TTL to 0. The number 0 is not defined in the standard, and it may cause your DNS information to be ignored or rejected.

Change TTL to higher value

Comment: 0 is not specifically defined in RFC1034 but nothing forbids it either. The zone will not be ignored or rejected (see with `named-checkzone` for example) but of course what will happen is that many recursive caches will just ignore this value as too low and put their own, like 300 for 5 minutes. In fact the 0 is probably just an artefact of some web UI if you do a DNS query you will see the records published with a TTL of 3600. So 0 in that provider is probably just a shortcut for some default local value.